# jquery keypress function fires at different times in different browsers

Tags: jquery, keypress

I am trying to automatically jump to the second line after a certain number of characters.  I am using the keypress function in jquery to do so.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://inet.website-name.com/jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="input1"></input>
    <br />
    <input id="input2"></input>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#input1').keypress(function (e) {
            var tval = $('#input1').val();
            if (tval.length >= 5 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
                $('#input2').focus();
            }
        })      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am encountering is when this is run in chrome the 6th character is typed in the first box followed by the focus changing to the second box.  When this is run in Internet Explorer, the focus is first changed to the second box and then the 6th character is typed.  I need it to have the same behavior in both browsers.

I tried using the keydown event and that worked in terms of changing the focus consistently but the focus would change even if I used the backspace, arrow keys or any other special key.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you missing a e.preventDefault(); before setting focus to the next control?

Comment: @3nigma - my mistake - it is e.preventDefault(); Edited my comment.

Comment: That is very helpful, but I still need the character to type in the second box.  How would I resend the event or send the character that was typed?

Comment: I figured out a way to do it after preventing default.
    if($('#input2').val() == ""){
    $('#input2').val( String.fromCharCode(e.which));}
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could switch it to a keyup event and it will work, though you will not be able to use the e.charCode check (is it there for a reason?). Also note that the **>= 5** was changed to a **> 5**

```
    $('#input1').keyup(function (e) {
         var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
         var isWordcharacter = c.match(/\w/);//matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _
         var tval = $('#input1').val();
         if (tval.length > 5 && e.which !== 0 && isWordcharacter) {
             $('#input2').focus();
         }
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbfcn/2aaBN/5/)

Comment: That is close but if you use arrow keys in the first box it changes the focus still.

Comment: And i guess i don't really need the e.charcode.  I had taken some of the code from another thread and wasn't sure why it was there so I left it.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by using the arrow keys, in the fiddle whenever pressing the arrow keys there is no effect since they do not change the length of tval.

Comment: If you type 6 characters it will jump to the next line.  But say I mess up the 5th character so I press at the end of the first box putting the cursor after the 6th character.  If I press the left arrow key to move the cursor, I sees that there are more than 5 characters and jumps to the next line.

Comment: you could restrict the focus change to only be on character inputs, answer updated